# Python json Bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have JSON objects that have multiple rows that should be inserted into the Google big Query Table
This is the sample:

```
[{"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:13", "city_name": "Dusseldorf", "pressure": 1015, "tempe": 294.84, "humidity": 58, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 20},
 {"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:14", "city_name": "Berlin", "pressure": 1017, "tempe": 294.81, "humidity": 60, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 100}, 
{"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:16", "city_name": "Munich", "pressure": 1016, "tempe": 296.04, "humidity": 57, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 100}]
```

and each time we have 3 records that should be inserted
but when I want to insert it face the below error :

```
Invalid value at 'rows[1].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""{""
Invalid value at 'rows[2].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""\"""
Invalid value at 'rows[3].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""t""
Invalid value at 'rows[4].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""i""
Invalid value at 'rows[5].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""m""
Invalid value at 'rows[6].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""e""
Invalid value at 'rows[7].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""s""
Invalid value at 'rows[8].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""t""
Invalid value at 'rows[9].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""a""
Invalid value at 'rows[10].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""m""
Invalid value at 'rows[11].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""p""
Invalid value at 'rows[12].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""\"""
Invalid value at 'rows[13].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), "":""
Invalid value at 'rows[14].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), "" ""
Invalid value at 'rows[15].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""\"""
Invalid value at 'rows[16].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""2""
Invalid value at 'rows[17].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""0""
Invalid value at 'rows[18].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), ""2""
Invalid ...
```

each character is divided into items
example: timestamp divided to:  t i m e s t a m p

I used `insert_rows_json`

what is the problem and how should I solve it?

Comment: How is the json being loaded? It should ideally be in newline delimited json format. one line for each json row.

Comment: this is not a file.it Takes data from API(weather API). you mean add newline in existed json object ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you provided indicates that the data being passed to Google BigQuery is not in the expected JSON format. It's attempting to interpret the data as a protobuf struct, but it's receiving characters that do not conform to the expected JSON structure.

The error message implies that the data sent to BigQuery lacks the correct JSON formatting. It might contain unexpected characters or encounter problems with proper escaping. To address this problem, it's crucial to verify that your data adheres to the correct format, resembling a JSON array of objects similar to the example data you originally supplied.

Make sure that you are passing a valid JSON array to BigQuery for insertion, and double-check the data format for any unexpected characters or syntax errors.

JSON format:

```
[
  {"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:13", "city_name": "Dusseldorf", "pressure": 1015, "tempe": 294.84, "humidity": 58, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 20},
  {"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:14", "city_name": "Berlin", "pressure": 1017, "tempe": 294.81, "humidity": 60, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 100},
  {"timestamp": "2023-09-15T17:46:16", "city_name": "Munich", "pressure": 1016, "tempe": 296.04, "humidity": 57, "wind_speed": 2.57, "clouds": 100}
]
```